# Object detection training does not start

Tags: tensorflow

Object detection training does not start:

```
(tensorflow_cpu) C:\Users\AB\Tensorflow\workplace\training_demo>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config


WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py:125: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py:266: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\object_detection\core\preprocessor.py:1240: calling squeeze (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) with squeeze_dims is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use the `axis` argument instead
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\AB\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\learning.py:737: Supervisor.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.supervisor) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession
2020-02-07 19:19:54.161321: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from training/model.ckpt-0
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
2020-02-07 19:20:24.185848: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\data\shuffle_dataset_op.cc:95] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 398 of 2048
2020-02-07 19:20:33.939501: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\data\shuffle_dataset_op.cc:95] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 547 of 2048
2020-02-07 19:20:43.980141: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\data\shuffle_dataset_op.cc:95] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 713 of 2048
2020-02-07 19:20:53.942496: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\kernels\data\shuffle_dataset_op.cc:95] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 871 of 2048
```

config

```
model {
    ssd {
        num_classes: 10
        box_coder {
            faster_rcnn_box_coder {
                y_scale: 10.0
                x_scale: 10.0
                height_scale: 5.0
                width_scale: 5.0
            }
        }
        matcher {
            argmax_matcher {
                matched_threshold: 0.5
                unmatched_threshold: 0.5
                ignore_thresholds: false
                negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
                force_match_for_each_row: true
            }
        }
        similarity_calculator {
            iou_similarity {
            }
        }
        anchor_generator {
            ssd_anchor_generator {
                num_layers: 6
                min_scale: 0.2
                max_scale: 0.95
                aspect_ratios: 1.0
                aspect_ratios: 2.0
                aspect_ratios: 0.5
                aspect_ratios: 3.0
                aspect_ratios: 0.3333
                reduce_boxes_in_lowest_layer: true
            }
        }
        image_resizer {
            fixed_shape_resizer {
                height: 300
                width: 300
            }
        }
        box_predictor {
            convolutional_box_predictor {
                min_depth: 0
                max_depth: 0
                num_layers_before_predictor: 0
                use_dropout: false
                dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
                kernel_size: 3
                box_code_size: 4
                apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
                conv_hyperparams {
                activation: RELU_6,
                regularizer {
                    l2_regularizer {
                        weight: 0.00004
                    }
                }
                initializer {
                        truncated_normal_initializer {
                            stddev: 0.03
                            mean: 0.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        feature_extractor {
            type: 'ssd_inception_v2' 
            min_depth: 16
            depth_multiplier: 1.0
            conv_hyperparams {
                activation: RELU_6,
                regularizer {
                    l2_regularizer {
                        weight: 0.00004
                    }
                }
                initializer {
                    truncated_normal_initializer {
                        stddev: 0.03
                        mean: 0.0
                    }
                }
                batch_norm {
                    train: true,
                    scale: true,
                    center: true,
                    decay: 0.9997,
                    epsilon: 0.001,
                }
            }
            override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
        }
        loss {
            classification_loss {
                weighted_sigmoid {
                }
            }
            localization_loss {
                weighted_smooth_l1 {
                }
            }
            hard_example_miner {
                num_hard_examples: 3000
                iou_threshold: 0.99
                loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
                max_negatives_per_positive: 3
                min_negatives_per_image: 0
            }
            classification_weight: 1.0
            localization_weight: 1.0
        }
        normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
        post_processing {
            batch_non_max_suppression {
                score_threshold: 1e-8
                iou_threshold: 0.6
                max_detections_per_class: 100
                max_total_detections: 100
            }
            score_converter: SIGMOID
        }
    }
}

train_config: {
    batch_size: 1
    optimizer {
        rms_prop_optimizer: {
            learning_rate: {
                exponential_decay_learning_rate {
                    initial_learning_rate: 0.004
                    decay_steps: 800720
                    decay_factor: 0.95
                }
            }
            momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
            decay: 0.9
            epsilon: 1.0
        }
    }
    fine_tune_checkpoint: "C:/Users/AB/Tensorflow/workplace/training_demo/pre-trained-model/model.ckpt" 
    from_detection_checkpoint: true
    num_steps: 200000
    fine_tune_checkpoint:"C:/Users/AB/Tensorflow/workplace/training_demo/pre-trained-model/model.ckpt"
    fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
    data_augmentation_options {
        random_horizontal_flip {
        }
    }
    data_augmentation_options {
        ssd_random_crop {
        }
    }
}

train_input_reader: {
    tf_record_input_reader {
        input_path: "C:/Users/AB/Tensorflow/workplace/training_demo/annotations/train.record" 
    }
    label_map_path: "C:/Users/AB/Tensorflow/workplace/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt" 
}

eval_config: {
    num_examples: 8000
    # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
    # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
    max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
    tf_record_input_reader {
        input_path: "C:/Users/AB/Tensorflow/workplace/training_demo/annotations/test.record" 
    }
    label_map_path: "C:/Users/AB/Tensorflow/workplace/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt" 
    shuffle: false
    num_readers: 1
}
```

OS Platform and Distribution : windows 10
Tensorflow : 1.9 cpu version
tran.py for training
I'm using the windows system installed in my MacBook Pro by BootCamp.    Sometimes when I run the training command, my computer crashed and turned to black screen. Does it have something to do with my training issues?

Comment: I'm using ssd_inception_v2_coco as pre-trained-model for training and the training does not start but stuck like that. Pls help. Thank you. ( Windows 10 OS and tensorflow cpu version 1.9)

Comment: Are you using `model_main.py` ? As I remember `model_main` is logging loss each 100 steps which can take a while on cpu. Maybe try using `legacy/train.py` which will print loss for each step and see if you are really stuck.

Comment: @sebastian-sz No. I'm using train.py. Thanks for your reply.